# Is it possible to make items within a column of an R data frame indexable?

Tags: json, r, list, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame, within which has indexable items.

By this I mean..

I currently have this structure:

```
X     Y     Z  
1     2     3
```

and I want to have

```
A          
c(1,2,3)
```

where I will be able to call A[1] in order to see the second value (for example).

So far I have used this:

```
Change <- paste(SNPs$V4, SNPs$V5, sep=",")
```

But this returns a string not an indexable list.

The reason for this is I will then convert my data frame into a JSON file, and need to be able to separate the elements easily.

EDIT

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "XXX", class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(3579L, 3585L, 37378L, 37625L, 46230L, 46340L), V3 = structure(c(4L, 
    6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("k31_cl0_BC_var_1081", "k31_cl0_BC_var_199", 
    "k31_cl0_BC_var_780", "k31_cl0_BC_var_852", "k51_cl0_BC_var_329", 
    "k51_cl0_BC_var_348"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C", "CT", "TT"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("C", 
    "G", "T"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = ".", class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "PASS", class = "factor"), 
    V8 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = ".", class = "factor"), 
    V9 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "GT:COV:GQ:SITE_CONF", class = "factor"), 
    V10 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("0/0:143,0:777.06:529.76", 
    "0/0:161,0:852.81:582.37", "0/0:163,0:846.27:999.60", "0/0:166,0:911.35:958.58", 
    "0/0:179,0:951.30:1404.56", "0/0:200,0:940.27:716.92"), class = "factor"), 
    V11 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("0/0:481,0:2692.68:582.37", 
    "0/0:630,0:3070.18:716.92", "0/0:665,0:3518.84:958.58", "0/0:691,0:3464.55:999.60", 
    "0/0:849,0:4096.86:1404.56", "1/1:0,581:3009.81:529.76"), class = "factor"), 
    V12 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("0/0:277,0:1474.49:582.37", 
    "0/0:323,0:1723.17:958.58", "0/0:347,0:1744.05:999.60", "0/0:349,0:1748.06:1404.56", 
    "0/0:356,0:1696.13:716.92", "1/1:0,282:1459.25:529.76"), class = "factor"), 
    V13 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("0/0:345,0:1870.48:582.37", 
    "0/0:404,0:1977.86:716.92", "0/0:439,0:2230.71:999.60", "0/0:467,0:2471.55:958.58", 
    "1/1:0,389:2014.25:529.76", "1/1:0,509:2504.55:1404.56"), class = "factor"), 
    V14 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("0/0:316,0:1615.78:999.60", 
    "0/0:408,0:2010.02:1404.56", "1/1:0,170:1016.14:582.37", 
    "1/1:0,205:1122.81:716.92", "1/1:0,307:1704.23:958.58", "1/1:0,311:1619.98:529.76"
    ), class = "factor"), V15 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 
    1L), .Label = c("0/0:179,0:934.24:999.60", "0/0:190,0:997.43:582.37", 
    "0/0:209,0:1124.87:958.58", "0/0:227,0:1067.85:716.92", "0/0:236,0:1173.70:1404.56", 
    "1/1:0,182:951.02:529.76"), class = "factor"), V16 = structure(c(5L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("0/0:256,0:1342.47:582.37", 
    "0/0:271,0:1334.45:999.60", "0/0:294,0:1572.75:958.58", "0/0:321,0:1565.49:1404.56", 
    "0/0:322,0:1490.25:716.92", "1/1:0,210:1112.15:529.76"), class = "factor"), 
    V17 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("0/0:162,0:827.57:999.60", 
    "0/0:171,0:887.59:582.37", "0/0:175,0:941.37:958.58", "0/0:198,0:963.49:1404.56", 
    "0/0:207,0:963.56:716.92", "1/1:0,137:701.77:529.76"), class = "factor"), 
    V18 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("0/0:229,0:1256.92:582.37", 
    "0/0:264,0:1330.53:716.92", "0/0:303,0:1639.95:958.58", "0/0:399,0:1899.69:1404.56", 
    "1/1:0,268:1400.21:529.76", "1/1:0,332:1649.86:999.60"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

perhaps you can see why I simplified.. I have StrSplit V10:V18, and selected some of the values, and want to concatenate these into a list within a column.

Comment: Please show the input data using `dput` as the structure is not clear.  If you have three columns with 1 row, use `unlist(yourdf)`.  If you want to convert to JSON format, `library(jsonlite);toJSON(yourdf)`

Comment: You can update the post with a subset of your data i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))`

Comment: Thanks for the structure.  You have 18 columns, What is your expected output?  Do you want to consider only V10:V18?

Comment: Do you want `as.character(unlist(df1[10:18]))`

Comment: I am not sure what you want, but before you put in lots of work look at the output of `jsonlite`.  If I do `jsonlite::toJSON(data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y =c(4,5,6)))` I get `[{"x":1,"y":4},{"x":2,"y":5},{"x":3,"y":6}]` which has the rows together (which is what I understand you want).

Comment: I have 18 columns, and will need V2, V10:V18. I have already used cbind to connect the columns i need, but the values in the latter columns are strings not numeric lists.

Comment: As I currently have the dateframe, the output is:[
  ["3579", "CT,C", "0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0", "716.92 716.92 716.92 716.92 716.92 716.92 716.92 716.92"], but i will need to  use each individual item from the list

Comment: I'm afraid you are missing some basics about [Subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).